# Java - Why can't I initialize the start value of a variable outside of a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

Is there a reason why I can't initialize the start value of a variable outside of a for loop? When I do this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int userInt = 1;
    int ender = 10;

    for (userInt; userInt < ender; userInt++) {
        System.out.println(userInt);
```

I receive a syntax error stating that userInt needs to be assigned a value, even though I've already assigned it a value of 1. When I do this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int userInt;
    int ender = 10;

    for (userInt = 1; userInt < ender; userInt++) {
        System.out.println(userInt);
```

The error goes away. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generic syntax for a Java `for loop` is as follows:

```
for ( {initialization}; {exit condition}; {incrementor} ) code_block;
```

This mean you can not just write down a variable name in the inizalization block. If you want to use an already defined variable, you just let it emtpy.

This should work for you:

```
for (; userInt < ender; userInt++) {
        System.out.println(userInt);
}
```

Comment: @TomFang: To answer why your original attempt failed: It's because "`userInt;`" is not a valid statement, and that's what you were attempting to evaluate in your original `for` loop.

Comment: Anything can go in initialization block, doesn't have to initialize anything. Just needs to be a valid statement as @JasonC said. This is the criticism I have. +1

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `for` statement expects an expression.

According to the [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14):

```
ForStatement:
    BasicForStatement
    EnhancedForStatement
```

And then:

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement

ForStatementNoShortIf:
    for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) StatementNoShortIf

ForInit:
    StatementExpressionList
    LocalVariableDeclaration

ForUpdate:
    StatementExpressionList

StatementExpressionList:
    StatementExpression
    StatementExpressionList , StatementExpression
```

As you see the basic for statement, first element is optional initialization, which is *either statement or local variable declaration*.

The statement is one of :

```
StatementExpression:
    Assignment
    PreIncrementExpression
    PreDecrementExpression
    PostIncrementExpression
    PostDecrementExpression
    MethodInvocation
    ClassInstanceCreationExpression
```

In your example `userInt = 1` is an `Assignment`, while just `userInt` doesn't match any of elements on the `StatementExpression` list, which causes compilation error.

Comment: +1 Great answer. To clarify, since its not shown (picking nits): It does not match `EnhancedForStatement` or `LocalVariableDeclaration` either.